# Share File To Dropbox from Application (MVC C#)

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox-api

Is there any way I can share file to user's dropbox folder ?

What I exactly want to implement is as below:

1. User Click on Dropbox icon.
2. Then Dropbox Asks for His/Her Dropbox account details.
3. File from Application Saved to his/her dropbox account.

I did search dropbox API's But did not get anything which helps me to save to user's Dropbox account. 
I read API Documentation ,
https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#files_put
, Here i can save files to my dropbox but not to other.

please guide me on the same. thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't "save" to the dropbox account, you should "share" the file. Nobody in their right mind would/should provide their dropbox username **and password** to a 3rd party website, but providing a dropbox account name for sharing purposes might not hold that security problem.

Comment: I think it is possible to provide a link that when the user clicks on it it will open his/her dropbox account and add the shared file to it, without you having to ask for anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if version 2 is any better for your purposes, but [version 1 of the API is deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/)

If the user has their Dropbox integrated with Explorer, then I would think you can just write to the local folder and it will sync up to Dropbox as usual.

Comment: So, I just need to find the Dropbox folder in user's local directory and add file there, Right ?

Comment: I haven't got Dropbox on this machine to test it. But the user would have to manually pick the location to save via the "Save As" dialog, because from a web app, you can't save directly to the user's drive. If a dialog is not acceptable guess you need to go back to the API docs - sorry...

Comment: Thanks for your support. I will update here with code once done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dropbox API to have a user authorize your app to access their Dropbox account and then programmatically save files to the account. (This works even if the user doesn't have the official Dropbox app installed.)

For .NET, we recommend using the official Dropbox API v2 .NET SDK:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet

The tutorial shows how to upload a file:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial

Comment: Thanks for the links. My requirement is in a way that I need not to use Dropbox API. I just need to save it in local folder and then it sync automatically t dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code snippet I Used to save Dropbox. I hope this will help mates.

```
// Code to retrieve Dropbox Local Folder
var infoPath = @"Dropbox\info.json";
        var jsonPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LocalAppData"), infoPath);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(jsonPath)) jsonPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData"), infoPath);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(jsonPath)) {
            return "-2";
        } 

        var dropboxPath = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(jsonPath).Split('\"')[5].Replace(@"\\", @"\");

        string fileName = "Your FileName";
        string sourcePath = Server.MapPath("Source Path Here");
        string targetPath = dropboxPath;

        // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, "filename.extention");
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

        // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
        // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
        }

        // To copy a file to another location and 
        // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(destFile))
        {
            System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime(destFile, DateTime.Now);
        }
```

Comment: I think this will not work as from web app we can not access Client's Folder. It worked for me initially as I tested locally.